# Display texting

Tags: displaystyle, displaybreak

I would like to learn what's the best way (most natural, canonical) to put in displayed form something like this [image]

Maybe align?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange-- the place where TeX lovers meet. To better interest enthusiasts, could you please break this down into two different questions and post them separately (with suitable titles)?  Finally, it would be great to get a starting code from you-- showing how you tried to do them (or saw them done somewhere), and want an improvement.  That would save contributors a lot of hard labour and increase your possibility of getting appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The first example looks like a table, you could try using `tabularx` to get the right margins and line breaking.

Comment: @ParthaD. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473745/how-to-arrange-commutative-diagrams-in-displayed-form for the second question.

Comment: I think the title of your question is inaccurate, as "texting" implies messages on handheld phones.  You might consider editing it.

Answer (score 7):

An itemized list would be, in my mind, canonical.  I say this because the math is all inline...things like `align` might be appropriate were the math displaystyle without surrounding text, but not here in this example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent the fibre or fibre category...
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1.2in,labelsep=.2in]
\item[\bfseries objects] $X \in\mathcal{E}$ with $pX = I$
\item[\bfseries morphisms] $x\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{E}_f$ are morphisms 
  in $f: X\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{E}$ for which $pf$ is the identity map 
  on $I$ in $\mathcal{B}$.
\end{itemize}
An object ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really wanted left-aligned labels, you can use the `itemize` option `align=left`.  I also zeroed `itemsep` so that the inter-item vertical gap is smaller.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent the fibre or fibre category...
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1.2in,labelwidth=.8in,labelsep=.2in,itemsep=0pt,align=left]
\item[\bfseries objects] $X \in\mathcal{E}$ with $pX = I$
\item[\bfseries morphisms] $x\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{E}_f$ are morphisms 
  in $f: X\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{E}$ for which $pf$ is the identity map 
  on $I$ in $\mathcal{B}$.
\end{itemize}
An object ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is clicking the up arrow the best way to show appreciation for an answer? What's the difference in clicking the checkmark? I'm sorry for the trivial questions, maybe I'm just too lazy to look for community regulations right now... If you could redirect me to such place I'd appreciate. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Vladimir You can click the up arrow on any question or answer on this site that you find "useful."  For questions that you yourself ask, once you have the possibly multiple answers to your question, you can also consider clicking the check mark to the left of the **one** answer that best answers your particular question.  This will help other readers to know which of the many answers were most helpful to the questioner.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have several of these descriptions, it is convenient to define a suitable environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newlength{\categorywd}

\newenvironment{category}
 {%
  \settowidth{\categorywd}{\textbf{morphisms}}%
  \addtolength{\categorywd}{2em}%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\categorywd}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{\categorywd}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
  }%
 }
 {\end{list}}

\newcommand{\objects}{\categorytype{objects}}
\newcommand{\morphisms}{\categorytype{morphisms}}
\newcommand{\categorytype}[1]{%
  \item[{\makebox[\categorywd][l]{\quad\textbf{#1}}}]%
}


\begin{document}

\noindent
the \textbf{fibre} or \textbf{fibre category} $\mathbb{E}_f=p^{-1}(I)$ over~$I$
is the category with
\begin{category}
\objects $X \in\mathbb{E}$ with $pX = I$.

\morphisms $X\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathbb{E}_f$ are morphisms 
  $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathbb{E}$ for which $pf$ is the identity map 
  on $I$ in $\mathbb{B}$.
\end{category}
An object blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Professor. I couldn't ask for a more complete answer. Being aware of your expertise in the field I think I'd like to ask you tons of questions in order to improve my document. I'll take the liberty to ask you here the following question: in order to define a command for the symbol to denote a category with, is it better to do it this way

\DeclareMathOperator{\ring}{\mathbf{Ring}}

or this way

\newcommand{\ring}{\textbf{Ring}},
and why? At my level of knowledge I cannot spot any differences. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Vladimir `\newcommand{\ring}{\mathbf{Ring}}`

Answer (score 1):

A `tabularx` environment is another solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent the \textbf{fibre} or \textbf{fibre category}… \medskip

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\quad} >{\bfseries}rX@{}}%
 objects & $X \in\mathcal{E}$ with $pX = I$ \\
 morphisms & $x\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{E}_f$ are morphisms
  in $f: X\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{E}$ for which $pf$ is the identity map
  on $I$ in $\mathcal{B}$.
\end{tabularx}
An object ...\bigskip

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\quad}>{\bfseries}lX@{}}%
 objects & $X \in\mathcal{E}$ with $pX = I$ \\
 morphisms & $x\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{E}_f$ are morphisms
  in $f: X\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{E}$ for which $pf$ is the identity map
  on $I$ in $\mathcal{B}$.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]