# How to arrange commutative diagrams in displayed form

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I would like to arrange the following three diagrams

```
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        Z\arrow[dr, "h", dashed]\arrow[drr, "g", bend left]\\
            &   X\arrow[r, "f"] &   Y
    \end{tikzcd}
\]

\[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        pZ\arrow[dr, "w", dashed]\arrow[drr, "pg", bend left]\\
            &   I\arrow[r, "u"] &   J
    \end{tikzcd}
\]

\[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        \mathbb{E}\arrow[d, "p"]\\
        \mathbb{B}
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
```

as they are arranged here:
[image]

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 8):

I'd use an `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
  \mathbb{E}\arrow[d, "p"]\\
  \mathbb{B}
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{aligned}
& \begin{tikzcd}
    \phantom{p}Z\arrow[dr, "h", dashed]\arrow[drr, "g", bend left]\\
    &   X\arrow[r, "f"] &   Y
  \end{tikzcd}
\\
& \begin{tikzcd}
    pZ\arrow[dr, "w", dashed]\arrow[drr, "pg", bend left]\\
    &   I\arrow[r, "u"] &   J
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

With `\phantom{p}` in the top right diagram, we ensure similarity with the bottom one.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How can I make the top right diagram similar to the bottom right in the following case?
 \[
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
   \mathbb{\famst}\arrow[d, "p"]\\
     \mathbb{\st}
  \end{tikzcd}
  \qquad\qquad
  \begin{aligned}
   \begin{tikzcd}
    \{X_i\}_{i\in I} \arrow[r, "f"] & \{Y_j\}_{j\in J}\\
          & \{Z_k\}_{k\in K}\arrow[ul, ""]\arrow[u, "g", swap]
   \end{tikzcd} 
   \\      
   \begin{tikzcd}
    I   \arrow[r, "pf=u"] & J\\
          & K\arrow[ul, ""]\arrow[u, "pg=v", swap].
   \end{tikzcd}
  \end{aligned}
 \]

Comment: @Vladimir You can adjust the bottom diagram by doing `\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=6em]` (adjust the length to suit).

Answer (score 3):

I would like to argue that it is much easier if you put things in one diagram. That way you have full and easy control over all dimensions. For instance, I added `[3em] after`&`to make the gap between the left and the right two diagrams a bit larger. And, of course,`\mathbb{E}`and`\mathbb{B}` are automatically aligned with the diagrams on the right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}
     &[3em]   Z\arrow[ddr, "h", dashed]\arrow[ddrr, "g", bend left]\\[-2em] 
\mathbb{E}\arrow[ddd, "p"]   & & & \\[-2em]
     &       &   X\arrow[r, "f"] &   Y\\
     & pZ\arrow[ddr, "w", dashed]\arrow[ddrr, "pg", bend left]\\[-2em] 
\mathbb{B}   & & & \\[-2em] 
     &     &   I\arrow[r, "u"] &   J\\
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here there is another proposal using `xy` package used to draw a `commutative-diagrams` to obtain your same image.

In this case I have used the ambient `minipage` to have the same structure of the your picture.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c][10mm]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\xymatrix@+1pc{
\mathbb{E} \ar[d]_p  \\
\mathbb{B}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\textwidth}\hspace{0cm}
\centering
\xymatrix@+.5pc{
Z  \ar@/^1.5pc/[drr]^g \ar@{-->}[dr]_h\\
& X  \ar[r]<3pt>_f & Y  
}
\vfill
\hspace{0cm}\xymatrix@+.5pc{
pZ  \ar@/^1.5pc/[drr]^{u\,\circ\, w\,=\,pg} \ar[dr]_w\\
& I  \ar[r]<3pt>_u & J  
}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```